# Can't click on anchor if it has an iframe inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

So basicaly I have this:

```
<a href="myurl">
    <iframe>...</iframe>
</a>
```

If I try to click on the `<a>` nothing happends. I also tried to add a class to my anchor and try to catch the event via jquery but nothing happends again.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I think you cannot put iframe inside `<a>` tag

Comment: Could you not just overlay the `<a>` tag over the top of the Iframe?

Comment: Take a look of the height of the anchor.

Comment: @ Germano Plebani - the height of the anchor is 100%, I checked that with firebug and it cover the content of the iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a hack to make this work using html only. So my example was [this](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/1pu8gwgd/):

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">
    <iframe style="width: 163px; height: 163px;" scrolling="no" src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>
</a>
```

and I figured [this](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/gqy772qp/) solution:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" style="position: relative; display: block; width: 163px; height: 163px;">
    <div style="position:absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0;"></div>
    <iframe style="width: 163px; height: 163px;" scrolling="no" src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>
</a>
```

Comment: So your solution is to *continue* using invalid HTML and hope browsers handle it the way you want? *Not* a good idea.

Comment: 1. I don't hope that browsers will handle the way I want, I just know they will do that.

Comment: 2. Sometimes clients force you to do stupid things, so you need to do them even if you like it or not, even if it has no sense. Considering this I had to find a solution for this case.

Comment: 3. It's easy to say "it's not good" and not post any solution to this. So your answer was helpful to know that it's not good, but it did not helped me to resolve the problem because you did not post any working example.

Comment: *"I just know they will do that"* No you don't. You know the ones you've tested will do that. You don't know that the next dot release of Chrome won't break it. Relying on broken HTML is a bad idea. If the client asks you to do something stupid, you gently guide them toward doing something not stupid.

Comment: And they will gently find somebody else to do their wish.

Comment: An regarding browsers, ussualy the newer they get, the better they get.

Answer (score 0):

Having an `iframe` inside an `a` is invalid HTML. If you have an invalid document, a browser can render and handle it however its authors see fit, including not doing what you were expecting.

[`a`'s content model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) is transparent, but there must be no [*interactive content*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0):

> **Interactive content** is content that is specifically intended for user interaction.
>
> => `a` `audio` (if the `controls` attribute is present) `button` `embed` **`iframe`** `img` (if the `usemap` attribute is present) `input` (if the `type` attribute is not in the `hidden` state) `keygen` `label` `object` (if the `usemap` attribute is present) `select` `textarea` `video` (if the `controls` attribute is present)

*(my emphasis on `iframe`)*

Instead, put the link in the `iframe`'s content.

Comment: I can't put the link in the iframe content because that iframe because I use it it many places and in other places I dont need that anchor inside the iframe.

Comment: @paulalexandru: That's easily solved, for instance with a query string parameter that JavaScript in the frame sees and shows/hides the link as appropriate. Bottom-line, you can't do what you're trying to do by putting the `iframe` in an `a` element, it simply will not work.

Comment: I tried with jquery and it did not work, anyways, I found a solution meantime using just html, you can check it bellow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an anchor for an iframe why not do it like this:

**index.html:**

```
<iframe src="iframe_page.html"></iframe>
```

**iframe_page.html:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="another_page.html">
    ...
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is invalid HTML. You should use some JavaScript to replicate the desired action. Hard to type code on my tablet but create a click action that takes you to the desired URL.